# Building $in array containing both strings and regex patterns

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a Mongo collection where every document in the collection has a sources array property.  Searches on this property can be a combination of exact matches and regex.  For example, when using Mongo shell, the query below searches for documents with source='gas valves' OR 'hose' is contained in source item.  This works just as I expect

```
db.notice.find({sources:{$in:[/\bhose/i,'gas valves']}})
```

Things get a little trickier in mgo.  Because some items in the $in array can be regex, and the others strings - the only way I have figured to make a query is by using $or:

```
var regEx []bson.RegEx
var matches []string
// do stuff to populate regEx and matches
filter["$or"] = []bson.M{
    {"sources":bson.M{"$in":regEx}},
    {"sources":bson.M{"$in":matches}},
}
```

Is there some way I could construct one slice with both regex and string to use with $in - eliminating the need for the $or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]interface{}`:

```
matches := []interface{}{
    bson.RegEx{"jo.+", "i"},
    "David",
    "Jenna",
}

db.C("people").Find(bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$in": matches}})
```

`[]` means slice and `interface{}` means any type. Put together, `[]interface{}` is a slice of any type.